# Python login and open url web page

Tags: python, url, authentication

I would like to make an authentication gateway in python

I would like to open an url following the execution of the following code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import cookielib, urllib, urllib2, getpass

#self.cookieJar = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()

toto = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()

#self.opener = urllib2.build_opener(
titi = urllib2.build_opener(
    urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(toto),
    urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler(),
    urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=0)
    )

#self.opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36")]
titi.addheaders = [('User-agent', "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36")]

forms = {
        "username": 'XXX' ,
        "password": 'XXX'
        }

data = urllib.urlencode(forms)
req = urllib2.Request('https://cc.fr/login/index.php',data)
print req.get_full_url()
res = titi.open(req)
tata = res.read()
print(tata)
```

I display the page after login but how to open in a browser ?

sorry I'm a beginner

Tx

Comment: Perhaps you should reconsider your variable name choices, `toto`, `titi` and `tata` are not the best readability-wise.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is you need some kind of software that can control a web browser fortunately for you there is something like that https://www.seleniumhq.org/. You can install it using `pip` It is designed to create unit test for web pages however many people use it to create bots or automation software. It provides bindings for many languages including python. You can easily open a browser, fill in forms etc. You also need to install a webdriver for the specific browser you use. The whole process is described on their site and it is pretty straightforward.

Comment: If this answer is not simple enough I can expand it

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I want to create a connection portal, type SSO but light with a redirection connection to more different applications.

Comment: Then I do not understand your question. The code sample you provided looks like a simple automation script I dunno how it could serve as SSO gateway.

Comment: yes exactly, I'm looking for a way in python to make a SSO gateway. With this code I can authenticate myself, so I think it must be possible to redirect an authenticated URL, right ?